# Angular execute a method on Component1 triggered from component2 (unrelated comps)

Tags: angular, typescript, angular9

I have 2 components.

Component1 and Component2

In component1 I have a method that is triggered by the user

```
<div (click)="trigger('parameter here')">run trigger</div>
```

Then on the .ts:

```
trigger(param) {
    // Code to "param" to send to Component2 and run executeThis()
}
```

In component2 I have another method:

```
executeThis(param) {
    console.log(param);
}
```

This 2 components are unrelated.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why does the code have to run in an unrelated component?
If they are truly unrelated you could move the code to a regular typescript file/class, no Angular component required.

Comment: Why don't you create a service for the `executeThis()` method?

Comment: By unrelated I mean that component 2 does not have <app-component1></app-component1> in the .html file of the component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a service for this.
In the service you declare a new EventEmitter:

```
export class TriggerService
{
  public trigger = new EventEmitter<any>();
}
```

Then in your component1 emit the event like this:

```
trigger(param)
{
  this.triggerService.trigger.emit(param);
}
```

And in your component2 subscribe on the EventEmitter:

```
constructor()
{
   this.triggerService.trigger.subscribe(param => {
     this.param = param;
     this.executeThis();
   });
}
```

And log param in executeThis:

```
executeThis()
{
  console.log(this.param);
}
```

Comment: This is a solution but, 1st you should remember to unsubscribe from the subscription on `ngOnDestroy` and 2nd, you should change `EventEmitter` with `Subject`, we usually put `EventEmitters` as parent child pipe and we use `Subjects` to on shared services.

Comment: the code is just updating `this.param`. If you want to `console.log(this.param)` whenever it changes then call `this.executeThis();` after `this.param = param;` in the constructor of component2. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject component2 inside component1. Then your trigger function become

```
trigger(param) {
  this.component2.executeThis(param);
}
```

Component2 would be actually a service.
See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injecting-services

If component2 is really a component (ie with html) I wuold move the code used by both components to a shared service.

Comment: Can I inject and still keep them as components?

Comment: Don't do that! Please!

Comment: Poor approach avoid doing that I am sharing a better approach hold on

Comment: Apart from edge cases (both components used in the same view) you can't inject a component inside a component. Use a service. A service is basically a component without HTML.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a shared service and using typescript accessor setter getter

**shared.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
 providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SharedService {
sharedValue;

constructor() {}

set someValue(value) {
  this.sharedValue = value
 } 

get someValue() {
  return this.sharedValue
 }
}
```

component 1 set value

```
constructor(private service: SharedService) {} // inject service

 trigger(param) {
 // set value
 this.service.someValue = param
}
```

component 2 get value

```
constructor(private service: SharedService) {} // inject service

executeThis() {
  // get value
  console.log(this.service.someValue);
}
```

Comment: This is almost perfect but executeThis() does not know when trigger() is called ... or at least executeThis() is not executing when trigger is run...I'm I forgetting something?

Comment: You need to trigger executeThis() manually or you can print the service value inside ngOnInit() depends upon your requirements, I dont know how you implemented.